# How to add required field message for decimal property using fluent validations in .net maui?

Tags: c#, maui, fluentvalidation

```
public class TemperatureModel
{
    public string TemperatureId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public decimal Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

In this Temperature field is the required filed and I want to add this validations using fluent validation library.

Taking value for temprature from user using MAUI's Entry control and I have write the rule like this:

```
RuleFor(_ => _.Temperature)
    .Must(t => t != default || t == 0).WithMessage("Temperature is required.")
    .WithMessage("Temperature accepts only decimal value.")
    .When(t => t != default)
    .GreaterThan(-9999999.99M).WithMessage("Min. temperature is -9999999.99")
    .LessThan(9999999.99M).WithMessage("Max. temperature is 9999999.99");
```

But when the there is no value in the Entry control it shows this error in **Application output** and "Temperature is required." error message is also not showing.

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: '(null)' 
cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'
```

Anyone have idea how to fix this?